# Inserting into a user-defined table type via a dynamic query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a user-defined table type `tyAnalysisNumbers`. I need to populate my user defined data type within a stored procedure with a `SELECT` statement and I am struggling to get that working within my stored procedure.

The following ways I have tried do not work

```
DECLARE @MyTable tyAnalysisNumbers;

INSERT INTO @MyTable 
    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @someTable);
```

I get this error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

I am unsure how to insert into my custom table via a select statement.

Can anyone help me accomplish this?

Comment: That should generally work so there's more going on not included in your script. Add a complete example to your question that reproduces the error.

Comment: I have two stored procedures, a parent one that calls a child. The child sp I am working is what uses the user defined table, works as is, you are right.

But it must be called from the parent stored procedure in our application, which has the following lines that are getting triggered - 

```

INSERT INTO @resultsTable execute childStoredProcedure

Commit Transaction

SELECT * FROM @resultsTable

End Try

Begin Catch

If XACT_STATE() <> 0
```

At which point errors are being logged to debugEvents and that is where I see the error `An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested`.

Comment: What is `@someTable`? The name of a permanent table? A table variable declared earlier in the code? A TVP?

Comment: @someTable is a schema and table name, permanent, not temporary.

Comment: Is this all the nested stored procedure does? Insert the output from some table into the table type, and then select it? Why bother with the table type? If there is other stuff that happens before the final select, please include that information and don't hide it or dumb it down. It's possible the solution is to just do everything in the dynamic SQL scope (or, if the set of operations performed after populating the type is large and/or the list of `@someTable` possibilities is small, there may be other solutions).

Comment: Also I really have to point out the potential SQL injection issue here, see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server-part-2/).

Comment: Seems like the outer stored procedure is just there to catch and log errors from the inner stored procedure.  That's basically all it does - tries the inner stored procedure, if it fails, then tries again a few times, logging errors.

Answer (score 0):

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested

Above error is self explanatory. Please look at below scenario:

For example, we have one procedure which inserts data in table type and return result.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertData1
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyTable tyAnalysisNumbers;

    INSERT INTO @MyTable 
    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM someTable');

    select * from @MyTable
END
```

Now, let's say we have another procedure which will call above procedure and again insert data in another table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspInsertData2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyTable tyAnalysisNumbers;

    INSERT INTO sometable
    EXEC uspInsertData1
END
```

Now, if you execute 1st procedure it will work fine but if you execute second procedure you will get this error.

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

Because now you have nested EXEC statements.

I suggest to finish your work in single stored procedure if possible.

Comment: This explains the OP's problem, but isn't a solution.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agree.. But I have also such scenarios but I never prefer or suggest to call such nested procedures. I always avoid such nested calls to prevent such side effects. I suggest to finish your work in single stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable tyAnalysisNumbers;
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM @MyTable;

DECLARE @tblName AS SYSNAME = (SELECT name FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @someTable);

EXEC ('INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT * FROM ' + @tblName);
```

This also addresses the SQL Injection problem.